# Error: Cannot find module 'commander'

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, npm-install, nvm

when I m running sails -v, sails lift or even installing npm I m getting this error Please help -

```
Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/bin/_commander.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling sails and reinstalling with `'sudo'` resolved it.

```
npm uninstall sails -g

sudo npm install sails -g
```

Comment: This did not fix it for me.

Answer (score 14):

Most likely `commander` is missing from `package.json`. Install it and add it to `package.json` by doing:

```
npm install commander --save
```

Answer (score 5):

Install `commander` globally.

`sudo npm install commander -g`

- This will install commander module under`/usr/lib/node_modules/`.

Answer (score 1):

When i try setup new app with the help of express-generator.
given error:Cannot find module 'commander'

```
Node version:12.16.1
switch node version :10.16.3
```

after switch node version is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of bad version of node. I've tried node 8.15.1 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, after doing `npm install`, and attempt to run `npm run watch` I encountered this same issue of `Error: Cannot find module 'commander'`.
I did below:

```js
// delete node_modules (can do manually) or command below
// rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

And I was able to do `npm run watch` again.
This maybe because of corrupted packages.