# Cannot find module 'commander'

Tags: npm, mocha.js

When I try and run my mocha tests I get

```
$ npm t

> digitalAlarmClock@1.0.0 test /home/durrantm/Dropnot/code/js/mochaChai/digitalAlarmClock
>  mocha *.test.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/nodejs/mocha/bin/_mocha
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/mocha/bin/_mocha:10:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/mocha/bin/_mocha' ]
}
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How to fix?

Comment: I suspect this question is "if Mocha is required and not installed, then you need to install it". I am not sure how useful that is though, so it may just be best to close the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'commander'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393301/error-cannot-find-module-commander)

Answer (score 2):

here's how I solve the issue:

run `npm list` to see if there's any dependency missing, for example, I saw:

```
[root@d21b188bb7e1 configurable-http-proxy]# npm list
configurable-http-proxy@4.3.2 /srv/configurable-http-proxy
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY commander@~7.2.0
...
```

install it manually by

```
npm install --save commander@~7.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for several different reasons.

In this case it is because mocha isn't installed.

Fix with

```
npm install --save-dev mocha
```